# Sorting IEnumerable<SelectListItem> by Text field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-objects

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong here, but I just can't get a sorted list when using:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<TEnumerable>(
    this IEnumerable<TEnumerable> enumerable,
    Func<TEnumerable, int> value,
    Func<TEnumerable, string> text)
{
    return enumerable.Select(
        item => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = value(item).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text = text(item)
        }).OrderBy(sli => sli.Text);
}
```

But when using the following, the list is ordered by 'Value' field without any issues:

```
    return enumerable.Select(
        item => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = value(item).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text = text(item)
        }).OrderBy(sli => sli.Value);
```

I would like the list to be sorted by 'Text' field. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't told us what *sort* happen with the first code. It should be fine as-is.

Comment: Your code looks fine. You should describe your problem with some sample data.

Comment: Verify your value() and text() functions don't have side effects, and be aware of lazy execution

Comment: @Jon Skeet, the OrderBy on the first piece of code does not have any effect at all whereas it does sort the collection by Value in the second piece of code.

Comment: @beastieboy: I'd be shocked to see that in action. Can you reproduce it with a short but complete example?

Comment: It appears to be a caching issue. Started working as expected after clearing the cache and rebooting! Thanks everyone.